# Is there an efficient way to generate a pseudo-boolean function from a linear constraint?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I would like to define a pseudo-boolean function $f$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for all logically valid combinations of $x\in{0,1}$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all logically invalid combinations of $x\in{0,1}$.

Suppose I have the following constraint where $x_i \in {0,1}$:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 2$

| $x_1$ | $x_2$ | $x_3$ | Valid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | Yes |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | Yes |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | Yes |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | Yes |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | Yes |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | Yes |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | No |

After binary expansion, it becomes quite trivial to see that the case $\{1,1,1\}$ is the only case that causes an invalid result.  As such, $f = x_1 \land x_2 \land x_3$ is an appropriate pseudo boolean function.

Is there an efficient way to reach this conclusion without a binary expansion?

Alternatively, I can surmise that the "invalid" cases are:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 > 1$

Since we are dealing with binary values, this is equivalent to:

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \geq 2$

That looks a little bit closer to $x_1 \land x_2 \land x_3$, but I'm still not sure...

Comment: You're asking for an efficient way to do something, which presumably means you're asking for an efficient algorithm.  What are the inputs to the algorithm?  Presumably some kind of specification of a constraint.  But what kinds of constraints are allowed?  Only a single linear constraint?  A conjunction of multiple linear constraints?  Something more general?

Comment: I suggest you read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics), https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/82033/755